# Binding a Kendo ComboBox to two model properties (one when an existing item is selected, one when a value is typed in)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-combobox

I don't know if this is something that is possible or not, but I'm having trouble finding the correct words to search for answers.

Let's say I have a "Location" model with these two properties. `City` corresponds to a column in the table with a foreign key to a lookup table of all cities in the local area. `CityOther` is a free-text field that allows users to enter any city name they want.

```
public int?   City      { get; set; }
public string CityOther { get; set; }
```

I have a Kendo `ComboBox` that's configured something like this:

```
@(Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(m => m.CityOther)
    .DataTextField("Text")
    .DataValueField("Value")
    .Placeholder("Select City")
    .Filter(FilterType.Contains)
    //.DataSource(d => ...)
)
```

When I serialize the form, I see two inputs with the names `CityOther` and `CityOther_input`.

When an existing city from the picklist is chosen, the values look like this:

```
{ name: 'CityOther'      , value: '3' }
{ name: 'CityOther_input', value: 'Springfield' }
```

When a free-text city (one not from the list) is entered, the values then look like this:

```
{ name: 'CityOther'      , value: 'Orlando' }
{ name: 'CityOther_input', value: 'Orlando' }
```

I would like to configure it so that:

1. a value selected from the existing list would end up in the `City` field (which means I would change it to `.ComboBoxFor(m => m.City)`).
2. a free-text value entered would end up in the `CityOther` field, rather than *XYZ`_input`*.

Is this possible?

Would model binding fail if the value in `City` (a nullable `int` property) was a string value?